# Exceptions for a Binary Search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am working on a Binary Search Tree for class, and the assignment instructions say that I should use 5 exceptions. I already came up with exceptions for duplicates, if an item cannot be found in the tree, and another which has to do with the input method. But I am having a lot of trouble coming up with more ways for a BST to falter than trying to operate on a non-existant node or a duplicate insertion.

Do you guys have any ideas on other potential issues which would require a unique exception?

Comment: Out of memory trying to allocate a node to insert. You could have different exceptions on find failure: The node you try to find is less than all others, greater than all others, or falls inside the range of values in the tree but just not in there. Attempting to  insert a null or otherwise invalid value. Quality real-world software would include integrity verification ... the tree implementation would (presumably for debug builds only) scan the entire tree to ensure it is in a valid state and assert / throw if not.

Comment: ok that's a good idea...I don't get the sense my prof had that in mind (bec. we never spoke in class about it), but if I can't think of any others, it's a good back up....How do you test if the stack is full or not? I've never done that before...

Comment: Not the stack, the heap.
When you do something like "Node p = new Node();", the "new" can fail. Typically this means that new will throw an OutOfMemory exception implicitly. You don't have to throw it yourself. Code trying to be robust against OOM will catch these exceptions and try to recover.

Comment: Is there a way to throw it myself--the prof. is very insistent that we throw our own exception whenever possible.

Comment: Sure, though the specifics depend on the language (you didn't say what language). just "throw OutofMemory". Its unlikely your prof would want you to throw this exception explicitly.

Comment: yeah, I don't think she did mean this one...tnx for your help! (I am working in java...)